# Optimizing data visualization on the GPU?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I have a process that accumulates mostly static data over time--and a lot of it, millions of data elements. It is possible that small parts of the data may change occasionally, but mostly, it doesn't change.

However, I want to allow the user the freedom to change how this data is viewed, both in shape and color.

Is there a way that I could store the data on the GPU just as data. Then have a number of ways to convert that data to something renderable on the GPU. The user could then choose between those algorithms and we swap it in efficiently without having to touch the data at all. Also, color ids would be in the data, but the user could change what color each id should match to, again, without touching the data.

So, for example, maybe there are the following data:

[1000, 602, 1, 1]
[1003, 602.5, 2, 2]

NOTE: the data is NOT vertices, but rather may require some computation or lookup to be converted to vertices.

The user can choose between visualization algorithms. Let's say one would display 2 cubes each at (0, 602, 0) and (3, 602.5, 100). The user chooses that color id 1 = blue and 2 = green. So the origin cube is shown as blue and the other as green.

Then without any modification to the data at all, the user chooses a different visualization and now a spheres are shown at (10, 602, 10) and (13, 602.5, 20) and the colors are different because the user changed the color mapping.

Yet another visualization might show lines between all the data elements, or a rectangle for each set of 4, etc.

Is the above description something that can be done in a straightforward way? How would it best be done?

Note that we would be adding new data, appending to the end, a lot. Bursts of thousands per second are likely. Modifications of existing data would be more rare and taking a performance hit for those cases is acceptable. User changing algorithm and color mapping would be relatively rare.

I'd prefer to do this using a cross platform API (across OS and GPU's), so I'm assuming OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your data in a VBO (in GPU memory) and update it when it changes.

On the GPU side, you can use a geometry shader to generate more geometry. Not sure how to switch from line to cube to sphere, but if you are drawing a triangle at each location, your GS can output "extra" triangles (ditto for lines and points).

As for the color change feature, you can bake that logic into the vertex shader. The idx (1, 2, ...) should be a vertex attribute; have the VS lookup a table giving idx -> color mappings (this could be stored as a small texture). You can update the texture to change the color mapping on the fly.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some way to optimize appending to a VBO? Since I may be adding data very quickly to it at times.
Also, in a geometry shader, does it have access to more than one point at a time such that it could create one shape per point in one case, but in other cases it would create one shape per multiple points?

Comment: `glBindBuffer` accepts a *target* param (which hints at whether this VBO will hold vertex or index data). `glBufferData` accepts a *usage* param (which hints at whether the data is static, dynamic or stream, and whether the app will read, copy or draw).

Comment: Also, what exact combination of hints will give **you** the best performance can only be discovered by profiling. It really comes down to your hardware + OpenGL driver version.

Comment: I clarified the question. Can VBOs store and geometry shaders work with non-vertex data? Maybe the data is 1, 2, 5 or 10 elements wide and then gets converted. Is this possible? Or would I have to use something like OpenCL? If necessary perhaps I could encode the data in whatever VBO requires and the GS could decode it?

Answer (score 0):

For applications like yours there are special GPGPU programming infrastructures: CUDA and OpenCL. OpenCL is the cross vendor system. CUDA is cross plattform, but supports only NVidia GPUs. Also OpenGL did introduce general purpose compute functionality in OpenGL-4.2 (compute shaders).

> and a lot of it, millions of data elements

Millions is not a very lot, even if a single element consumed 100 bytes, that would be then only 100 MiB to transfert. Modern GPUs can transfer about 10 GiB/s from/to host system memory.

> Is the above description something that can be done in a straightforward way? How would it best be done?

Yes it can be done. However only if you can parallelize your problem and make it's memory access pattern cater to what GPUs prefer you'll really see performance. Especially bad memory access patterns can cause several orders of magnitude performance loss.